# Put grid below plot in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

In a plot with pgfplots I would like to draw, from background to foreground, in the following order:

1. (background) grid;
2. (intermediate layer) plot;
3. (foreground) axis.

As specified [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/358221/74786),

> Adding `axis on top` to the axis options means axis lines, ticks and
>   grids are printed on top of the stuff inside the environment.

So, this is not the correct option for this. This code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{
    /pgfplots/layers/Bowpark/.define layer set={
        axis background,axis grid,main,axis ticks,axis lines,axis tick labels,
        axis descriptions,axis foreground
    }{/pgfplots/layers/standard},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[/pgfplots/layers/Bowpark,
             width=\textwidth,
             xmin=-0.5, xmax=6,
             ymin=-0.5, ymax=4,
             axis line style = thin,
             axis lines=middle,
             axis line style={-{Stealth[length=2.5mm]}},
             thick,
             grid=major, grid style={dashed,gray!30}]

    \addplot[blue, samples = 100] {x^2};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

doesn't work neither (plot is above grid, but also above the axis). I used `\addplot[blue, samples = 100] {x^2};` instead of `\addplot[samples = 100] {x^(1/2)};` to better highlight the superposition of the plot, the grid and the axis.

[image]

[image]

What's wrong? Note that also trying

```
\pgfplotsset{
    /pgfplots/layers/Bowpark/.define layer set={
        axis background,main,axis grid,axis ticks,axis lines,axis tick labels,
        axis descriptions,axis foreground
    }{/pgfplots/layers/standard},
}
```

(switched the order of `main` and `axis grid`) produces the same output.

Maybe something in my configuration ignores the layers order?

Comment: The easiest way is probably to use `axis on top` but draw the grid by hand, behind the plot.

Comment: @HenriMenke As far as I understood, the fact that axis and grid go together, complicates the problem. Having several plots with different axis *max* and *min* values would make quite troublesome also to draw by hand the grid each time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is discussed at length in section 4.27 of the [`pgfplots` manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots). All I did is to define a new `layer set` based on `axis on top` in which I flip the order of `axis grid` and `main`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{
    /pgfplots/layers/Bowpark/.define layer set={
        axis background,axis grid,main,axis ticks,axis lines,axis tick labels,
        axis descriptions,axis foreground
    }{/pgfplots/layers/standard},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=\textwidth,
             xmin=-0.5, xmax=6,
             ymin=-0.5, ymax=4,
             axis line style = thin,
             axis lines=middle,
             axis line style={-{Stealth[length=2.5mm]}},
             thick,
             grid=major, grid style={dashed,gray!30},
             set layers=Bowpark]

    \addplot[blue, samples = 100] {x^2};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: Fixed bug, I was too sloppy, sorry!

---

**Edit 2022-10-30 by User [Manuel Kuehner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/14649/dr-manuel-kuehner)**

If you use the `fillbetween` library, it seems you must also include the `pre main` in the list. In my case, I put `pre main` it before `main`

> Package pgfplots Warning: 'fill between': Could not activate graphics
> layer 'pre main'. Filled path will be on top of the other ones. Please
> ensure that 'pre main' is somewhere in the layer list (or set
> '/tikz/fill between/on layer=').

---

Comment: +1. Very good. I'm deleting my answer. With of sincerity I have not seen well the screen.

Comment: I suspect that something in my environment ignores the layers order. Please, check out my edited question for more details about your code. And anyway thank you

Comment: @BowPark Yes, you're right, I was too sloppy. You need to say `set layers=Bowpark` to activate the layers. My bad!

Comment: Its a sign of a great marmot that they tidiy up after themselves :-)

Comment: Don't worry and thank you so much. It works exactly as in your image!