# How to hide axis labels (except some of them) inside axis environment without disabling a grid?

Tags: tikz-pgf, axis, ticks

Let's say you want to draw a plot:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{babel,calc,backgrounds,quotes,angles,patterns,decorations.markings,intersections,arrows,arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}                       
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
                axis lines = middle,
                axis line style = {-Latex[round],very thick},
                % enlargelimits = true,
                grid = both,
                grid style={help lines},
                xmin = -4,
                ymin = -3.1,
                xmax = 4,
                ymax = 4,
                xtick = {-3, ..., 3},
                ytick = {-3, ..., 3},
                xlabel style={below right},
                ylabel style={above left},
                x tick label style={below left},
                samples = 100,
                axis on top=true,
                xlabel = {$x$}, 
                ylabel = {$y$},
              ]
    \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);
    
    \addplot[very thick, color=Mahogany] {-x^2 + 2};

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

How to make some fancy changes:

1. make x tick labels below right for negative x and below left for positive x;
2. show tick labels only for these points: (0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (0, -1)? If I change xtick = {-3, ..., 3} and ytick = {-3, ..., 3}, it will change the grid, but I want to keep it as it is for {-3, ..., 3) ticks.

Comment: Remove the unnecessary libraries.

Comment: "labels below right for negative x, but no negative x!?

Comment: @hpekristiansen that was not clear. the post is edited

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

In the first try, according to OP comment,  apparently I do not understood question. The second try is based on guessing, but I'm not sure what is desired result ...

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
%
                babel % for languages issues, not needed in this MWE
                } % other libraries are not used
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
%\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween} % not used

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        width=9cm,  % enlarged image width
    axis lines = middle,
    axis line style = {-Latex[round], very thick},
    % grid,
    xmin = -3.5,    xmax = 3.5,
    ymin = -3.5,    ymax = 3.5,
    xtick = {-3,...,3},
        % added, for tick labels placements
        tick style = {major tick length=3mm, 
                      semithick, 
                      color=black},
        xticklabels={,,$-1$, , , , },
        xticklabel style = {inner sep=2pt,
                            anchor=north west,
                            font=\footnotesize},
        extra x ticks={0,1},                
        extra x tick labels={0,1},
        extra x tick style={tick label style={xshift=-0.9em}},
        yticklabels=\empty,                  
        extra y ticks={-1,1},                
    xlabel = {$x$},
    ylabel = {$y$},
    xlabel style={below right},
    ylabel style={above left},
    axis on top,
        samples = 100,  %
             ]
\addplot[very thick, color=Mahogany] {-x^2 + 2};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. However, the grid is now all over the place) Grey lines are over Oy, over the plot of -x^2 + 2 - is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @Allok: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/456859/put-grid-below-plot-in-pgfplots

Comment: @Allok, the answer is almost as you request in question. Now I see, that I forgot on two labels. I can add them, however, fors please, clarify, what you like to have.  Grid you can remove by deleting option `grid` in `axis` options.

Comment: @Zarko, thanks again for the answer. I edited the post to clarify the problem. yes, I'd like to have the same grid (as it was for {-3, ..., -3} ticks)

Comment: @hpekristiansen, thanks for the link

Comment: @Allok, sorry, after your edit of the question is (to me) even less clear.